# Dynamic subject line in Marketing Cloud using external data source

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, json, automation

I have an automated email that has content which is populated entirely from Movable Ink.

The Movable Ink content is feed by a JSON feed from a website, so content is updated on the site and is automatically reflected in the email. Cool, huh =)

Can Salesforce Marketing Cloud accept this JSON feed too, so that it could pre-populate the subject line for this email?

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is no out-of-the-box solution, but it can be achieved by a combination of AMPscript and SSJS.

Firstly I will describe how to populate subject, and then how to retrieve data from JSON.

### Populating subject

Subject line, similarly to preheader, can be populated by AMPscript, which is evaluated in the email body.

In the subject line, you can put just code responsible for displaying proper variable:

```
%%=v(@subject)=%%
```

And in the body of the email, you can populate the variable with this simple code snippet:

```
%%[VAR @subject
SET @subject = "Some content" ]%%
```

### Getting data from JSON

This is where we need to combine AMPscript and SSJS. The shortest known to me way to achieve that is using SSJS option to make HTTP request and parse returned value, using `eval` function.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1")
    var response = HTTP.Get('http://www.example.com');
    var jsonObject = eval("(" + response.Content + ")");
</script>
```

AMPscript has his own HTTP request handling functions, but I haven't seen an option to parse JSON in it, so that is the reason why I suggest to combine another technology in this solution.

Passing value to AMPscript can be achieved by one of the native functions:

```
<script runat="server">
     var subject = evaluatedJSON.navigate.through.object.to.find.subject;
     Platform.Variable.SetValue("@subject",subject);
</script>
```

---

### Combining end solution

The final solution, from email's body, can look like:

```
%%[VAR @subject]%%
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1")
    var response = HTTP.Get('http://www.mynews.com/fresh.json');
    var jsonObject = eval("(" + response.Content + ")");
    var subject = jsonObject.news[0].subject;
    Platform.Variable.SetValue("@subject",subject);
</script>
```

Of course, this is only one of the possibilities. There is more than one way to achieve before-mentioned business requirement in Marketing Cloud environment.

---

### Efficiency considerations

> Thanks to [Adam Springs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) for suggestion about caching.

Making request on each email composition is not an optimal way to deliver content to Marketing Cloud, especially if we prepare large send-out. Upper presented solution will make HTTP request each time the email will be prepared, to leverage that, one of the workarounds may be to cache the output of that webservice in Data Extension.

It can be achieved using **Automation Studio** and SSJS activity from within. This script can download and parse JSON from your source (as presented in previous points) and save the content in Data Extension using built-in DE functions (vide: [Marketing Cloud SSJS documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/)).

If you know how often you will be triggering your send out or you know how often content in that source will be updated, then you can easily setup that automation to be scheduled in given time - before need to use that data.

Comment: This. Yes.  I'd recommend writing this data to a Data Extension with a Script Activity outside of the email.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs From the optimisation point of view,  making a request at the moment of composing of each message, especially if the send-out is large, won't be optimal. You are right. I will enrich my answer with the suggestion to cache output of that webservice in data extension. Thank you!

Comment: **WOW** guys, thank you so much! I'll try and get this set up. Can't thank you enough for your input. Josh

Comment: @jroobz No problem! Possibility to share knowledge is very rewarding, especially if it is useful for someone.